# Using static strings in TypeScript for AngularJS constant

Tags: typescript

I want to reference the names for a constant by using static data, but it does not work out, because of the execution order. How should this be done.

```
module tasks {

    export class TasksController {

        //name of the controller used for referencing or defining this controller
        public static named: string = 'tasksController';
        public static templateUrl: string = 'apps/demo/tasks/tasks.tpl.html';

        //dependencies to other services etc., referenced in the constructor
        static $inject: string[] = ['tasksConfig'/*TasksConfiguration.named*/];

        //constructor getting injected dependency instances
        constructor(appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration) {
        }

    }


    angular
        .module('Tasks', [])
        .controller(TasksController.named, TasksController);
}


module tasks {

    export class TasksConfiguration {

        //id of the configuration used for referencing or defining
        public static named = 'tasksConfig';

        public static values: ApplicationConfiguration = {
            appId: 'demo.tasks',
            appName: 'App_Name_Tasks',
            appCategory: 5,
            rootUrl: '/tasks'
        };
    }

    angular.module('Demo')
        .constant(TasksConfiguration.named, TasksConfiguration.values);
}
```

The $inject does not work, when I use TaskConfiguration.named instead of 'taskConfig' because it is not initialised, when the interpreter reaches the line. But what can I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

> but it does not work out, because of the execution order

In general this is a risk you run into with [`out`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md).

In your case you can just reorder the classes :

```
module tasks {

    export class TasksConfiguration {

        //id of the configuration used for referencing or defining
        public static named = 'tasksConfig';

        public static values: ApplicationConfiguration = {
            appId: 'demo.tasks',
            appName: 'App_Name_Tasks',
            appCategory: 5,
            rootUrl: '/tasks'
        };
    }

    angular.module('Demo')
        .constant(TasksConfiguration.named, TasksConfiguration.values);
}

module tasks {

    export class TasksController {

        //name of the controller used for referencing or defining this controller
        public static named: string = 'tasksController';
        public static templateUrl: string = 'apps/demo/tasks/tasks.tpl.html';

        //dependencies to other services etc., referenced in the constructor
        static $inject: string[] = ['tasksConfig'/*TasksConfiguration.named*/];

        //constructor getting injected dependency instances
        constructor(appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration) {
        }

    }


    angular
        .module('Tasks', [])
        .controller(TasksController.named, TasksController);
}
```

Or even better *move to external modules*.

> In reality these are two files placed in different angular modules. Maybe there is another way to inject dependencies?

Indeed Use external modules and steer clear of `--out`. More : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: In reality these are two files placed in different angular modules. Maybe there is another way to inject dependencies?

Comment: @dec yup that's why I said use external modules. I've more docs for your perusal

Comment: Okay. I understand you suggest me to use another build tool to put all together, and not the --out option of TypeScript. Right?

Comment: I am not using out. I got several js files but the ordering of including and executing these is undefined, I think

Comment: `but the ordering of including and executing these is undefined` < How are you loading these files ... that is the tool ordering these for you at the moment